# Fmod include errors

Tags: header, c++-cli, fmod

I am making a C++ program to play some mp3 files and am running into trouble. I am getting identifier not found errors. Can anyone give me some advice besides including the header?

Here is my code:

```
#include "fmod.h"
#include "windows.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
#include <conio.h>

#pragma comment (lib, "fmodex64_vc.lib")

using namespace System;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Collections;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace std;

/// <summary>
/// Summary for Form1
/// </summary>
public ref class Form1 : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
{

public:
    FSOUND_SAMPLE* handle;
    Form1(void)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //
        //TODO: Add the constructor code here
        //
    }

protected:
    /// <summary>
    /// Clean up any resources being used.
    /// </summary>
    ~Form1()
    {
        if (components)
        {
            delete components;
        }
    }
private: System::Windows::Forms::TextBox^  textBox1;
protected: 
private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::ListBox^  list;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;


private:
    /// <summary>
    /// Required designer variable.
    /// </summary>
    System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
    /// <summary>
    /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
    /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
    /// </summary>
    void InitializeComponent(void)
    {
        this->textBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::TextBox());
        this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
        this->list = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::ListBox());
        this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
        this->SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // textBox1
        // 
        this->textBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(97, 23);
        this->textBox1->Name = L"textBox1";
        this->textBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(518, 20);
        this->textBox1->TabIndex = 0;
        this->textBox1->TextChanged += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::textBox1_TextChanged);
        // 
        // label1
        // 
        this->label1->AutoSize = true;
        this->label1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(12, 26);
        this->label1->Name = L"label1";
        this->label1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(79, 13);
        this->label1->TabIndex = 1;
        this->label1->Text = L"Libray Location";
        // 
        // list
        // 
        this->list->FormattingEnabled = true;
        this->list->Location = System::Drawing::Point(15, 80);
        this->list->Name = L"list";
        this->list->Size = System::Drawing::Size(757, 472);
        this->list->TabIndex = 2;
        // 
        // button1
        // 
        this->button1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(697, 571);
        this->button1->Name = L"button1";
        this->button1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button1->TabIndex = 3;
        this->button1->Text = L"Play";
        this->button1->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button1->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button1_Click);
        // 
        // button2
        // 
        this->button2->Location = System::Drawing::Point(616, 571);
        this->button2->Name = L"button2";
        this->button2->Size = System::Drawing::Size(75, 23);
        this->button2->TabIndex = 4;
        this->button2->Text = L"Refresh";
        this->button2->UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this->button2->Click += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &Form1::button2_Click);
        // 
        // Form1
        // 
        this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
        this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
        this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(784, 606);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
        this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->list);
        this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
        this->Controls->Add(this->textBox1);
        this->Name = L"Form1";
        this->Text = L"Form1";
        this->ResumeLayout(false);
        this->PerformLayout();

    }

    private: System::Void textBox1_TextChanged(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

    }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
        std::string standardString = context.marshal_as<std::string>(textBox1->Text);
        GetAllFiles(standardString);
        //list->Items->Add();

    }

    void GetAllFiles(string sPath){
    WIN32_FIND_DATA FindFileData;
    string sTmpPath = sPath;
    sTmpPath += "\\*.*";

    HANDLE hFind = FindFirstFile( sTmpPath.c_str(), &FindFileData );

    if ( hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE )
        return;
    else {
        do {
            if ( ( FindFileData.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY ) ) {
        // if directory:
                if ( strcmp(".", FindFileData.cFileName ) && strcmp("..", FindFileData.cFileName) ) {
            sTmpPath = sPath;
                    sTmpPath += "\\";
            sTmpPath += FindFileData.cFileName;
                    GetAllFiles( sTmpPath.c_str() );
                }
            }
            else // if file:
            {
                sTmpPath = sPath;
                sTmpPath += "\\";
                sTmpPath += FindFileData.cFileName;
                string fileType = sTmpPath.substr(sTmpPath.length()-3, sTmpPath.length());
                if(fileType == "mp3"){
                    String^ myTempPath = gcnew String(sTmpPath.c_str());
                    list->Items->Add(myTempPath);//cout << sTmpPath << endl;
                }
            }
        } while ( FindNextFile( hFind, &FindFileData) != 0 );

        FindClose( hFind );
    }
    return;
}

    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        // init FMOD sound system
        FSOUND_Init (44100, 32, 0);

        // load and play mp3
        handle=FSOUND_Sample_Load (0,"E:\\Steve\\Music\\2 Pac\\Unknown Album\\Temptations.mp3",0, 0, 0);
        FSOUND_PlaySound (0,handle);
        FSOUND_Sample_Free (handle);
        FSOUND_Close();
    }
```

};

Here are my errors:

```
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(26): error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(26): error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(187): error C3861: 'FSOUND_Init': identifier not found
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h (190): error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(190): error C3861: 'FSOUND_Sample_Load': identifier not found
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(191): error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h (191): error C3861: 'FSOUND_PlaySound': identifier not found
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(192): error C2065: 'handle' : undeclared identifier
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(192): error C3861: 'FSOUND_Sample_Free': identifier not found
1>c:\users\steve\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\testforms\testforms\Form1.h(193): error C3861: 'FSOUND_Close': identifier not found
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 0):

Mmmh just double check if you have the semicolon at the end of your header file, and if you have defined it "#ifndef" ... it's easy to forget

Comment: I did that and I added semicolons to each include just in case still no go. Do you want me to upload the project folder to see?